# Is GC Profiling still slow in Ruby 2.2 and 2.3?

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, profiling, memory-profiling

I read [here](http://www.codinginthecrease.com/news_article/show/156863) that GC profiling was slow on Ruby 1.9.3.
We used to run our Ruby on Rails app on Ruby 1.9.3 but now we run it on Ruby 2.2 and plan to upgrade it to Ruby 2.3.

We'd like to enable GC profiling in order to collect that data for New Relic.
Is GC profiling still slow in Ruby 2.2 or 2.3? How much performance degradation should I expect?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Turn it on for a few minutes and have a look at your New Relic graphs.

Comment: I can, but asking other's experience first can provide more information about the pitfalls and merits of enabling GC profiling. Maybe someone saw this problem before me and can save me some downtime/unresponsiveness of my app.